# Move Rows to top in angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-table

I have created a mattable and it is working perfectly fine. I am changing the values of the last column from 'No' to 'Yes' by comparing JSON property values with other JSON values.

So far this is working fine but now I want to move those rows to the top whose last column values will be changed to 'Yes'.

I am getting an observable in my component and that observable is directly bound to mattable. The business logic is implemented in the smart component while the dumb component is only showing data. Here is my dumb component code.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$" class="mat-elevation-z8">


    <ng-container matColumnDef="srNo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Sr No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index"> {{i + 1}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Parcel ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="zone">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Zone </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getZone(element)}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="zoneArea">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Zone Area </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getZoneArea(element)}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="customerAddress">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Customer Address </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.customerData.address}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="vendor">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Vendor </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.vendor.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Scanned </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
            <p class="text-bold" [ngClass]="{'green-fg': element.currentStatusId == statusRepo?.id,'red-fg' : element.currentStatusId !== statusRepo?.id}">
                {{element.currentStatusId == statusRepo?.id ? 'YES' : 'NO'}}

            </p>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

component.ts file

```
export class WarehouseParcelListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() dataSource$: Observable<IParcel[]>;
    @Input() statusRepo: IStatusRepository;
    tableArray: IParcel[] = [];
    data: MatTableDataSource<any>;
    displayedColumns = [
        'srNo',
        'id',
        'zone',
        'zoneArea',
        'customerAddress',
        'vendor',
        'status'
    ];
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    getZone(parcel: IParcel) {
        return parcel.zoneArea ? parcel.zoneArea.zone.name : null;
    }
    getZoneArea(parcel: IParcel) {
        if (parcel.zoneArea) {
            return parcel.zoneArea.name;
        }
        return parcel.zoneAreaId;
    }

}
```

Smart Component HTML file

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end end">
    <app-parcel-id-input (submitId)="submitId($event)" *ngIf="(dataSource$ | async)?.length> 0" class="w-40-p">
    </app-parcel-id-input>
</div>


<app-warehouse-parcel-list [statusRepo]="statusRepository" [dataSource$]="dataSource$"></app-warehouse-parcel-list>
```

Smart component ts file

```
export class WarehouseParcelScanRiderComponent implements OnInit {
    dataSource$: Observable<IParcel[]>;
    statusRepository: IStatusRepository;
    constructor(
        private _ac: ActivatedRoute,
        private _http: WarehouseScanParcelHttpService,
        private _sb: SwyftSnackBarService,
        private _localStorageService: LocalStorageService
    ) {
        this._ac.params.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params);
            if (params.pickupBatchId) {
                this.fetchPickupBatch(params.pickupBatchId);
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
    submitId(parcelId: string) {
        this.dataSource$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(data => {
            if (data.filter(x => x.id === parcelId).length === 0) {
                return this._sb.open({
                    message: 'Invalid parcel ID',
                    type: 'warning'
                });
            }
            const filterParcels = () => {
                return this.dataSource$.pipe(
                    flatMap(parcels =>
                        forkJoin([
                            of(parcels),
                            parcels.filter(p => p.id === parcelId)
                        ])
                    )
                );
            };
            const processData = (localStorageData: any) => {
                return filterParcels().pipe(
                    flatMap(data => {
                        if (
                            data[1].currentStatusId === this.statusRepository.id
                        ) {
                            this._sb.open({
                                message: 'This parcel is already scanned',
                                type: 'info'
                            });
                            return of(false);
                        }
                        return forkJoin([
                            of(data[0]),
                            this._http.createParcelStatus(
                                parcelId,
                                this.statusRepository.id,
                                localStorageData['userId']
                            )
                        ]);
                    })
                );
            };
            this._localStorageService
                .getLocalStorageItem('pc_admin_data')
                .pipe(
                    flatMap(processData),
                    take(1)
                )
                .subscribe(data => {
                    if (isBoolean(data)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    const index = data[0].findIndex(obj => obj.id === parcelId);
                    console.log(index);
                    const temp = [...data[0]];
                    console.log(temp);
                    temp[index].currentStatusId = this.statusRepository.id;
                    this.dataSource$ = of(temp);
                    console.log(temp);
                    console.log(this.dataSource$);
                });
        });
    }
    fetchPickupBatch(pickupBatchId: string) {
        console.log('fetchinggg shitt');
        const getParcelStatuses = (parcel: IParcel) => {
            return this._http
                .getParcelStatuses(parcel.id)
                .pipe(map(data => ({ parcel, statuses: data })));
        };
        const transformParcels = (
            parcels: IParcel[]
        ): Observable<IParcel[]> => {
            const data = of(parcels).pipe(
                mergeAll(),
                mergeMap(getParcelStatuses),
                toArray(),
                map(_data =>
                    _data
                        .filter(obj => {
                            return obj.statuses.findIndex(
                                _obj =>
                                    _obj.statusRepositoryId ===
                                    this.statusRepository.id
                            ) === -1
                                ? true
                                : false;
                        })
                        .map(filteredData => filteredData.parcel)
                )
            );
            return data;
        };
        const fetchCustomerData = (customerDataId: string) => {
            return this._http.getCustomerData(customerDataId);
        };
        const fetchParcelZoneArea = (zoneAreaId: string) => {
            return this._http.getZoneArea(zoneAreaId);
        };
        const fetchParcelZoneAreaAndCustomerAddress = (parcel: IParcel) => {
            if (
                parcel.zoneAreaId === 'INVALID_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS' ||
                parcel.zoneAreaId === 'ZONE_NOT_DEFINED'
            ) {
                return forkJoin([
                    fetchCustomerData(parcel.customerDataId),
                    of(null)
                ]);
            }
            return forkJoin([
                fetchCustomerData(parcel.customerDataId),

                fetchParcelZoneArea(parcel.zoneAreaId)
            ]);
        };
        const appendZoneDataAndCustomer = (parcel: IParcel) => {
            return fetchParcelZoneAreaAndCustomerAddress(parcel).pipe(
                map(data => {
                    const mappedParcel = parcel;

                    if (data[1]) {
                        mappedParcel.zoneArea = data[1];
                    }
                    mappedParcel.customerData = data[0];
                    return mappedParcel;
                })
            );
        };
        const fetchParcelVendor = (parcel: IParcel) => {
            return this._http.getVendorById(parcel.vendorId).pipe(
                map(vendor => {
                    const mappedParcel = parcel;
                    mappedParcel.vendor = vendor;
                    return mappedParcel;
                })
            );
        };
        this._http.getStatusRepository().subscribe(repo => {
            this.statusRepository = repo;
            this.dataSource$ = this._http
                .getPickupBatchById(pickupBatchId)
                .pipe(
                    mergeMap(pickupBatch => of(pickupBatch.parcelBatchIds)),
                    mergeAll(),
                    mergeMap(parcelBatchId =>
                        this._http.getBatchParcels(parcelBatchId)
                    ),

                    toArray(),
                    mergeMap(dArray => of(dArray.flat())),
                    mergeMap(transformParcels),
                    mergeAll(),
                    mergeMap(appendZoneDataAndCustomer),
                    mergeMap(fetchParcelVendor),
                    toArray(),
                    tap(parcels => {
                        if (parcels.length === 0) {
                            this._sb.open({
                                message: 'No parcels found to scan',
                                type: 'info'
                            });
                        }
                    })
                ) as Observable<IParcel[]>;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: any help please,  I am stuck here.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec can you help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this.

---

i think you can use matSort table with default sort

in component.html file

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource$" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8" matSortActive="name" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>

....

    <ng-container matColumnDef="status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Scanned </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
            <p class="text-bold" [ngClass]="{'green-fg': element.currentStatusId == statusRepo?.id,'red-fg' : element.currentStatusId !== statusRepo?.id}">
                {{element.currentStatusId == statusRepo?.id ? 'YES' : 'NO'}}

            </p>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
```

component.ts file

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';


export class WarehouseParcelListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() dataSource$: Observable<IParcel[]>;
    @Input() statusRepo: IStatusRepository;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;



    tableArray: IParcel[] = [];
    data: MatTableDataSource<any>;
    displayedColumns = [
        'srNo',
        'id',
        'zone',
        'zoneArea',
        'customerAddress',
        'vendor',
        'status'
    ];
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {

    this.dataSource$.sort = this.sort;

    }

    getZone(parcel: IParcel) {
        return parcel.zoneArea ? parcel.zoneArea.zone.name : null;
    }
    getZoneArea(parcel: IParcel) {
        if (parcel.zoneArea) {
            return parcel.zoneArea.name;
        }
        return parcel.zoneAreaId;
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to create a stackblitz. I am working with a different branch right now and cannot test your code. Would very much appreciate if you can create a simple demo on stackblitz

Comment: you can check this. it have st column is already sorted and user can't clear that sort result